# Inequality with complex number

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following homework question for a course in complex analysis:

Determine all the $z\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|\sin z| ≤ 1$, and find an $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|\sin(in)| > 10 000$.

I have however no clue how to do this, also because during the lecture the teacher said that is no ordering in the complex numbers. I tried substituting $\sin(z)=\frac{1}{2i}(e^{iz}$ - $e^{-iz})$ but this didn't bring my any further.

Comment: The complex numbers aren't ordered, but $|\sin(in)|$ is real.  Also, you made a typo in you formula for $\sin z,$ didn't you?

Comment: You're right! I keep forgetting the $i$ in the denominator..

Answer (score 1):

The substitution is a good hint: by letting $z=x+iy$ we get
$$\sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz} - e^{-iz}}{2i}=\sin(x)\cosh(y)+i\cos(x)\sinh(y).$$
Hence
$$\begin{align}
\lvert\sin(z)\rvert^2&=\sin(x)^2\cosh(y)^2+\cos(x)^2\sinh(y)^2
\\&=
\sin(x)^2\cosh(y)^2+(1-\sin(x)^2)\sinh(y)^2\\
&=\sin(x)^2+\sinh(y)^2.
\end{align}$$
Can you take it from here?